# Поворот изображения

Tags: java, android

Даётся **Image**:

```
 ImageSaver(Image image) {
           
            
        }
```

Необходимо как-то повернуть этот image. В интернете я нашёл такой класс:

```
package com.loopgamestudio.photographya;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Build;


public class ExifUtil {


    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

            if (orientation == 1) {
                return bitmap;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case 2:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
                default:
                    return bitmap;
            }

            try {
                Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                return oriented;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        try {
            /**
             * if your are targeting only api level >= 5
             * ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
             * orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                Class <? > exifClass = Class.forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
                Constructor <? > exifConstructor = exifClass.getConstructor(new Class[] {
                        String.class
                });
                Object exifInstance = exifConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] {
                        src
                });
                Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt", new Class[] {
                        String.class, int.class
                });
                Field tagOrientationField = exifClass.getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
                String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
                orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance, new Object[] {
                        tagOrientation, 1
                });
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orientation;
    }
}
```

И мог бы использовать его вот так:

```
     ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {

            mImage = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap("1",image);
        }
```

Но в том классе работа происходит над BitMap, а у нас Image.

Возможно надо либо конвертировать Image в Bitmap, а затем назад, либо проводить поворот непосредственно над самим Image

Answer (score 0):

Вроде ничего сложного

```
 your_image.setRotation(90);
```